# Split dropdown buttons not the same size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having the weirdest error ever! I am using code line by line from twitter bootstrap components page  for the dropdown and I am not getting the same results.
Here is what my drop down is looking like.

[image]

I have **NOT** overriden any bootstrap css. I even removed ALL stylesheets and used JUST the button and I still get the same result.

PS: I am using rails will-paginate-bootstrap plugin..which I assume has all necessary bootstrap files

**Here is my HTML output**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/user/profile/test_user">
    <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>
     test_user
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're not using the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`).

From [Bootstrap's documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global):

> Bootstrap makes use of certain HTML elements and CSS properties that
>   require the use of the HTML5 doctype. Include it at the beginning of
>   all your projects.

Comment: I'm curious exactly what feature of html5 makes this difference. Any idea?

Comment: I've been burned by this: somehow (probably due to some copying/pasting or saving between platforms), my doctype declaration had a few extra whitespace bytes in front of it.  Firefox didn't complain, but Chrome rendered as if it wasn't an HTML5 doc.  In my case, the extra characters were extra BOM codes.  Deleting them made the doctype work, and the bootstrap buttons render correctly.

Comment: Most handy answer ever!! Thank you so much!